# lab problems for corse

Tags: java, android

hey every one i am sorry but i have to ask this question, it seems like a very easy issue but i just stuck! i have spent the last 2 hours going through the form and android developer resource site and i cant find the problem with my code. 
first of all the startActivityForResult() will not send me the text back.
second every time i click on the Implicit Activation button the app crashes.

here is the main activity file:

```
public class ActivityLoaderActivity extends Activity {

static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
static private final String URL = "http://www.google.com";
static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";

// For use with app chooser
static private final String CHOOSER_TEXT = "Load " + URL + " with:";

// TextView that displays user-entered text from ExplicitlyLoadedActivity runs
private TextView mUserTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_loader_activity);

    // Get reference to the textView
    mUserTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    // Declare and setup Explicit Activation button
    Button explicitActivationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.explicit_activation_button);
    explicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Call startExplicitActivation() when pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startExplicitActivation();

        }
    });

    // Declare and setup Implicit Activation button
    Button implicitActivationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.implicit_activation_button);
    implicitActivationButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Call startImplicitActivation() when pressed
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startImplicitActivation();

        }
    });

}


// Start the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity

private void startExplicitActivation() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered startExplicitActivation()");

    // TODO - Create a new intent to launch the ExplicitlyLoadedActivity class
    Intent explicitIntent = new Intent (ActivityLoaderActivity.this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
    // TODO - Start an Activity using that intent and the request code defined above
    startActivityForResult(explicitIntent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);

}

// Start a Browser Activity to view a web page or its URL

private void startImplicitActivation() {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered startImplicitActivation()");

    // TODO - Create a base intent for viewing a URL
    // (HINT:  second parameter uses Uri.parse())
    Intent baseIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(URL));

    // TODO - Create a chooser intent, for choosing which Activity
    // will carry out the baseIntent
    // (HINT: Use the Intent class' createChooser() method)
    Intent chooserIntent = null;
    chooserIntent.createChooser(baseIntent, CHOOSER_TEXT);



    Log.i(TAG,"Chooser Intent Action:" + chooserIntent.getAction());


    // TODO - Start the chooser Activity, using the chooser intent
    startActivity(chooserIntent);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");

    // TODO - Process the result only if this method received both a
    // RESULT_OK result code and a recognized request code
    // If so, update the Textview showing the user-entered text.
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
           mUserTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("resulttext"));
}}}
```

and here is the explicit intent file:

```
public class ExplicitlyLoadedActivity extends Activity {

static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";

private EditText mEditText;
String resulttext="still waiting";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.explicitly_loaded_activity);

    // Get a reference to the EditText field
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    // Declare and setup "Enter" button
    Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter_button);
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        // Call enterClicked() when pressed

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            enterClicked();

        }
    });

}

// Sets result to send back to calling Activity and finishes

private void enterClicked() {

    Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

    // TODO - Save user provided input from the EditText field
    resulttext= mEditText.getText().toString();
    // TODO - Create a new intent and save the input from the EditText field as an extra
    Intent returntrip = new Intent ();
    returntrip.putExtra("wayback", resulttext);
    // TODO - Set Activity's result with result code RESULT_OK
    setResult(RESULT_OK, returntrip);
    // TODO - Finish the Activity
    finish();
}
```

}

thank you guys so much i know i am a bother!

Comment: Please post the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending an extra data called "`wayback`" not "`resulttext`"

```
 returntrip.putExtra("wayback", resulttext);
```

this will fix your code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
          mUserTextView.setText(data.getStringExtra("wayback"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you won't get the result back correct from your `onActivityResult` because you are not using the correct key.  You look inside for `data.getStringExtra("resulttext")` but you originally set the key as "wayback".  You need to grab with that key.